# Auto layout for textfield and label in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

[image]I am trying to create a static tableview for sign up form. I have label and textfields. I want to apply auto layout such that label and textfields are visible but I am not able to achieve that for iPhone but it seems to work for iPad, since, I guess iPad are bigger. I have applied height and aspect ratio constraint to textfield. I have pinned labels to the left edge of the textfield. 
[image: Sample of applied autolayout]

[image: This is how it looks in iPhone, but I intend to make it look similar to the simulator]

Comment: I'm a little confused. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: also just change the storyboard mode to iphone 4 inch and see that everything is right?

Comment: @Rajan Maheshwari I want to avoid checking for specific device and make it dynamic such that for any device I run it on should fit both, if necessary by automatically reducing the sizes of textfields.

Comment: thats what I told. Just design your interface in inferred mode in storyboard and add constraints. They will be automatically adjusted with every device...dynamically

Comment: Autolayout should be independent of the screen size; make sure that you pin the right side of the textfield and the leftside of the labels to the container. And put a horizontal constraint between each label-textfield pair.

Comment: @Koen I have done exactly the same, I have thought about putting both textfield and label inside a uiview and add the constraint to the view instead of each labels and textfield and clip subview. But I was wondering if there is another robust way to do so.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari I have used auto layout and inferred.

Comment: @Rosh: could you add a picture that shows all the constraints? Since you are using a `UITableView`, you can use the the `contentView` of each cell as you container.

Comment: @Koen I just edited the question to show all the constraints I have applied. Thanks

Comment: @CalebKleveter I want both labels and textfields visible in each row of the tableview, but on phone 5s it only shows textfields

Comment: @Rosh, I don't see any horizontal constraints between the label and text and the enclosing view. See for instance the yellow/orange lines here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Comment: I also don't see any constraints for 'L', I assume that is the label?

Comment: @Koen Thanks Koen, I was not sure where the horizontal constraint should be for the textfield, but I have maneuvered it now. I have added a small view , which is set horizontally and vertically centered in the container and i have given the constraints based on that view, trailing for label to view and leading for textfield to view and the trailing 0 to container view. Seems to work fine but I wanted to do it without view. I wanted to see all the labels to be match the trailing for "confirm password" so that complexed the issue for the other labels. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Landscape mode][image: Added a view in the middle to use that view as a reference]

I used the view (with thickness 2) and centered it vertically and horizontally to use as a reference point.